# Magento 2.x - Save same model data in multiple databases

Tags: magento2, database, data-replication

I have a very big B2B eCommerce which is based on websites (each website has different products, customers etc).

For each website I need to have different databases. I have achieved such a thing but now i need to synchronize some information that will be the same on all websites (so in all databases).

I have a main store that will be the master store and when something changes in CMS Module, Blog Module etc. in master it should be replicated to all other databases.

I do not want to make this replication in sql and i was wondering if it is possible to save/update a model directly by using resource connections of Magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did tests and researches and finally came out with a solution.
Each store will have its own domain. I have created a master store who knows all other stores including itself. Every other store has just the master store and the current store.

EX US Store has 2 stores

- US -> us.store.com
- Master -> master.store.com

In code I created and observer listening to `modelnamehere_save_after` event for each model i want to sync.

When model is saved and event is triggered, if we are in master store(the store that admin will use) i have a foreach loop as below:

```
foreach ($websites as $website) {
    $defaultStore = $website->getDefaultStore();
    if (is_null($defaultStore)) {
        continue;
    }
    $baseUrl = $defaultStore->getBaseUrl();
    $serverName = parse_url($baseUrl)['host'] ?? '';
    if (empty($serverName) || ($website->getId() == $mainWebsite->getId()) || ($mainWebsiteServerName == $serverName)) {
        continue;
    }
    $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = $serverName;
    $params = $_SERVER;
    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
    $obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

    $modelToReplaceFactory = $obj->get(get_class($object));
    $modelToReplace = $modelToReplaceFactory->load($object->getId());

    $modelToReplace->setData($object->getData());
    $modelToReplace->save();
}
```